# SQL Hierarchy over multiple tables and result in multiple lines (not JOINING)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to query a Oracle DB, where data is contained in different tables. I have simplified it as follows:

```
Table Catalog, fields: ID, Code, Label
Table Catalogstructure, fields: ID, Code, Label, CatalogID
Table Catalogsegment, fields: ID, Code, Label, CatalogID, ParentID, StructureID
```

One Catalog has one structure, and a structure has many segments. ParentID in Catalogsegment contains the ID from the Catalogsegment, that is above of the selected one. The highest Catalogsegments don't have any ParentID.

The result I want is on different lines, first the Catalog with ID, Code and Label, then the structure with ID, Code and Label and finally, from top to down, all the Catalogsegments with ID, Code and Label.

Sample Data:

```
Catalog:
1000, C1, Catalog 1
2000, C2, Catalog 2

CatalogStructure:
1100, CS1, Structure 1, 1000
1200, CS2, Strcuture 2, 1000
2100, CS3, Structure 3, 2000

CatalogSegment:
1101, CSS1, Segment 1, 1000, null, 1100
1102, CSS2, Segment 2, 1000, 1101, 1100
1103, CSS3, Segment 3, 1000, 1102, 1100
1104, CSS4, Segment 4, 1000, 1003, 1100
1201, CSS5, Segment 5, 1000, null, 1200
1202, CSS6, Segment 6, 1000, 1201, 1200
2101, CSS7, Segment 7, 2000, null, 2100
2102, CSS8, Segment 8, 2000, 2101, 2100
```

Result:

```
1000, C1, Catalog 1
1100, CS1, Structure 1
1101, CSS1, Segment 1
1102, CSS2, Segment 2
1103, CSS3, Segment 3
1104, CSS4, Segment 4
1200, CS2, Structure 2
1201, CSS5, Segment 5
1202, CSS6, Segment 6
2000, C2, Catalog 2
2100, CS3, Structure 3
2101, CSS7, Segment 7
2102, CSS8, Segment 8
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result. Also what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data and results you showed, the hierarchy doesn't matter; you can just union together queries against the three tables, and order by the three IDs - where present:

```
with t (c_id, cs_id, css_id, code, label) as
(
  select c.id, null, null, c.code, c.label
  from catalog c
  union all
  select cs.catalogid, cs.id, null, cs.code, cs.label
  from catalogstructure cs
  union all
  select css.catalogid, css.structureid, css.id, css.code, css.label
  from catalogsegment css
)
select code, label
from t
order by c_id, cs_id nulls first, css_id nulls first;
```

| ID | CODE | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | C1 | Catalog 1 |
| 1100 | CS1 | Structure 1 |
| 1101 | CSS1 | Segment 1 |
| 1102 | CSS2 | Segment 2 |
| 1103 | CSS3 | Segment 3 |
| 1104 | CSS4 | Segment 4 |
| 1200 | CS2 | Structure 2 |
| 1201 | CSS5 | Segment 5 |
| 1202 | CSS6 | Segment 6 |
| 2000 | C2 | Catalog 2 |
| 2100 | CS3 | Structure 3 |
| 2101 | CSS7 | Segment 7 |
| 2102 | CSS8 | Segment 8 |

If the segments IDs aren't in order as you've shown and you want to order them according to the hierarchy then you can introduce a recursive CTE to feed the third branch; or more simply here just make the third branch hierarchical:

```
with t (c_id, cs_id, css_id, id, code, label) as
(
  select c.id, null, null, c.id, c.code, c.label
  from catalog c
  union all
  select cs.catalogid, cs.id, null, cs.id, cs.code, cs.label
  from catalogstructure cs
  union all
  select css.catalogid, css.structureid, level, css.id, css.code, css.label
  from catalogsegment css
  start with parentid is null
  connect by catalogid = prior catalogid
  and structureid = prior structureid
  and parentid = prior id
)
select id, code, label
from t
order by c_id, cs_id nulls first, css_id nulls first;
```

That doesn't affect the result [with your sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e216141aa1331d193a75130c9952f9e6), at least with the 1003 parent corrected to 1103; but if the parent/child relationships are shuffled slightly [then it does change the result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b99930f1cabd124971646d11285bab7b).

Comment: IMO I don't think we should give solution base on specific dataset.  As it will fail when data is out of our assumption, and when it happen, the time and cost to fix bug is much more than the initial time-saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT
  NVL(c.ID,NVL(s.ID,cs.ID)) as ID,
  NVL(c.CODE,NVL(s.CODE,cs.CODE)) as CODE,
  NVL(c.LABEL,NVL(s.LABEL,cs.LABEL)) as CODE
FROM
  Catalog as c,
  Catalogstructure as s,
  Catalogsegment as cs
WHERE
  c.ID = s.CATALOGID
  AND c.ID = cs.CATALOGID
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query using `ROLLUP`

```
WITH catalog AS
(
    SELECT 1000 AS id, 'C1' AS code, 'Catalog 1' AS label FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2000, 'C2', 'Catalog 2' FROM dual 
)
, catalogstructure AS
(
    SELECT 1100 AS id, 'CS1' AS code, 'Structure 1' AS label, 1000 AS catalogid FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1200, 'CS2', 'Strcuture 2', 1000 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2100, 'CS3', 'Structure 3', 2000 FROM dual
)
, catalogsegment AS
(
    SELECT 1101 AS id, 'CSS1' AS code, 'Segment 1' AS label, 1000 AS catalogid, null AS parentid, 1100 AS structureid FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1102, 'CSS2', 'Segment 2', 1000, 1101, 1100 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1103, 'CSS3', 'Segment 3', 1000, 1102, 1100 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1104, 'CSS4', 'Segment 4', 1000, 1003, 1100 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1201, 'CSS5', 'Segment 5', 1000, null, 1200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1202, 'CSS6', 'Segment 6', 1000, 1201, 1200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2101, 'CSS7', 'Segment 7', 2000, null, 2100 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2102, 'CSS8', 'Segment 8', 2000, 2101, 2100 FROM dual 
)
, join_table AS 
(
    SELECT c.id, c.code, c.label, 
        st.id AS st_id, st.code AS st_code, st.label AS st_label,
        se.id AS se_id, se.code AS se_code, se.label AS se_label
    FROM catalog c 
    LEFT JOIN catalogstructure st
    ON c.id = st.catalogid
    LEFT JOIN catalogsegment se
    ON c.id = se.catalogid AND st.id = se.structureid
)
, r_table AS 
(
    SELECT id, MAX(code) AS code, MAX(label) AS label,
        st_id, MAX(st_code) AS st_code, MAX(st_label) AS st_label,
        se_id, MAX(se_code) AS se_code, MAX(se_label) AS se_label
    FROM join_table
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (id, st_id, se_id)
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN se_id IS NOT NULL THEN se_id 
        WHEN st_id IS NOT NULL THEN st_id
        ELSE id
    END AS id,
    CASE 
        WHEN se_id IS NOT NULL THEN se_code
        WHEN st_id IS NOT NULL THEN st_code
        ELSE code 
    END code,
    CASE 
        WHEN se_id IS NOT NULL THEN se_label 
        WHEN st_id IS NOT NULL THEN st_label
        ELSE label
    END AS label
    --, r.*
FROM r_table r
WHERE r.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY r.id NULLS FIRST, r.st_id NULLS FIRST, r.se_id NULLS FIRST;
```

Tested in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40237e/21)

[image]